# Cisco arp inspection in 'log only' mode

Tags: cisco

Is there a ready way to enable Dynamic Arp Inspection (DAI) **without** having it in blocking mode to begin with? Failing that is there a good way to gather arp statistics from each interface over a prolonged period so I can scale my settings correctly?

I'm mostly concerned with Cisco stacking switches, 3750 range. There is a lot of concern because turning this on does have the potential to err-disable ports right off the bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a mac address access-list bypass but it would be very chatty so be sure you have a syslog setup.

```
ip arp inspection filter staticmacs vlan XXX
arp access-list staticmacs
 permit ip any mac any log
```

You could also just trust every port in your stack and selectively turn off the arp inspection trust in a controlled rollout to verify your results.

```
myswitch1(config-if)#ip arp inspection trust
```